# Power BI-Custom Column, check if value is date or text

Tags: date, if-statement, powerbi

I am trying to add a custom column in the query editor that returns the value of a column if it is a date and null if the value is text.

```
=if(isdate[Report Due Date]) then [Report Due Date] else null
```

I get the error message that isdate is not recognized, can someone please tell me the expression to use for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
= if ([Report Due Date] is date) then [Report Due Date] else null
```

Comment: So close yet so far away...THANKS!!